# "Where" Condition in RDLC Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, rdlc

I have a table like :

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| 8.75 | J |
| 5.05 | T |
| 6.1 | T |
| 8.5 | J |

I want to sum ColumnA data where ColumnB = J and show it in one of the RDLC textboxes.

What I should write in the Expression Field?

Comment: At first glance, [How to sum a field based on a condition in another field in RDLC report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29642065/how-to-sum-a-field-based-on-a-condition-in-another-field-in-rdlc-report) appears to contain enough information for you to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression.

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ColumnB.Value, 1) = "J", CDbl(Fields!ColumnA.Value), 0)
```

Use `IIF( expr truepart,falsepart)` to determine if the value is J, and `Sum()` to calculate the sum.

Comment: thanks for helping me , I get this error :
the Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox105.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Comment: Please make sure using "yourdatasetname" to replace 1 in the expression.